# invocar tres funciones definidas previamente en una nueva función/ PYTHON

Tags: python, funciones, function, funcion

Use las funciones definidas para actualizar todas las entradas en el diccionario de tarjetas.

Implemente la función rewrite_data para reescribir el diccionario usando las funciones remove_empty_options, remove_newline y answer_option.

Finalmente, actualice el diccionario de tarjetas llamando a la función rewrite_data.

```
def remove_empty_options(card):
   for k in list(card):
       if card[k]=='':
           del card[k]
   return card

def remove_newline(card):
   question = card['Questions']
   card['Questions'] = question.strip()
   return card

def answer_option(card):
   correct_answer=card['Correct']
   for k in ['A','B','C','D'] and  ['A','B']:
       if card[k] == correct_answer:
           card["Correct"] = k
   return card
```

```
cards["animals"][0]
>>> {'Questions': 'Three of these animals hibernate. Which one does not?\n',
  'Correct': 'Sloth',
  'A': 'Mouse',
  'B': 'Sloth',
  'C': 'Frog',
  'D': 'Snake'}
  
cards["animals"][1] 
 >>>{'Questions': 'All of these animals are omnivorous except one.\n',
  'Correct': 'Snail',
  'A': 'Fox',
  'B': 'Mouse',
  'C': 'Opossum',
  'D': 'Snail'}
  
  cards["animals"][2] 
>>> {'Questions': 'Three of these Latin names are names of bears. Which is the odd one?\n',
  'Correct': 'Felis silvestris catus',
  'A': 'Melursus ursinus',
  'B': 'Helarctos malayanus',
  'C': 'Ursus minimus',
  'D': 'Felis silvestris catus'}
```

Ejemplo:.

Example:

```
cards["science-technology"][0]
>>> {'Questions': 'Immanuel Kant criticized Emanuel Swedenborg and termed him a "spook hunter".\n',
  'Correct': 'True',
  'A': 'True',
  'B': 'False',
  'C': '',
  'D': ''}
rewrite_data(cards)
cards["science-technology"][0]
>>> {'Questions': 'Immanuel Kant criticized Emanuel Swedenborg and termed him a "spook hunter".',
 'Correct': 'A',
 'A': 'True',
 'B': 'False'}
```

Código intentado:

```
define rewrite (card):
        remove_empty_options(card)
        remove_newline(card)
        answer_option(card)
        return card
```

Comment: Es solo `def`. Si prestas atención en el resaltado de código, no identifica la palabra clave `define`.

Comment: Como te han dicho es `def` y no `define`, pero además tienes que llamar a la función poniendo `rewrite(card)`, donde tienes que sustituir `card` por el dato o variable correspondiente que le quieras pasar como parámetro, a no ser que sea una variable llamada `card` precisamente....

Comment: No veo una pregunta por aquí ...